# Need help on background colour on selected image mouse down. and remove the background to other image that is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

//this gives me background colour yellow on img, but if i select another img it will not remove the backround colour on the first selected img :

```
$('img').mousedown(function() {
    var $selectedDiv = $(this).parent();
    var divId = $selectedDiv.attr('id');
    currentCol = divId [1];
    currentRow = divId [3];
    $("#r"+currentCol+"c"+currentRow).css("background", "Yellow");
});
```

Comment: Please post an example of your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do :

```
$('img').mousedown(function() {
    $('img').css('background', ''); // This will set back the background colour to whatever colour you need image to be.
    // You can now process the current image.
    var $selectedDiv = $(this).parent();
    var divId = $selectedDiv.attr('id');
    currentCol = divId [1];
    currentRow = divId [3];
    $("#r"+currentCol+"c"+currentRow).css("background", "Yellow");
});
```

Comment: Note that if you just want to remove a property, `$('img').css('background', '');` will just remove this particular `background` property.

Comment: I would have gone with JQuery's `siblings()` method, though. Just so OP doesn't shoot too large.

Comment: the point is to make the img backgroundcolor yellow when I click it until i drop it, and leave it yellow where i drop it

Comment: You mean drag and drop images in a grid ?

Answer (score 0):

how about simple replace your

```
$('img').mousedown(function() {....});
```

with

```
$('img').mouseover(function() {....});
```

i think that should solve your problem.